# Could not synchronize database state

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a Java class **ClassA**, this class has hibernate mappings defined.
Somewhere in the code, i need to retrieve all instances of this class saved in the database:

```
public List<ClassA> getAllClassA(){
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(ClassA.class);
    return crit.list();
}
allA = getAllClassA();
```

Later i will delete some object, while updating the others:

```
public void removeItem() {
    Iterator<ClassA> it = allA.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ClassA cA = it.next();
        if(cA.hasCondition()){
            dao.remove(cA);
            it.remove();
        }
        else {
            cA.update();
        }
    }
    dao.update(allA);
}
//this is in another class
public void update(List<ClassA> allA){ //dao.update
    for(ClassA cA: allA){
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(cA);
    }
}
```

What happens is that the database is correctly updated (and the desired object removed) but it also spits out the following error:

> ERROR
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions:324
>   - Could not synchronize database state with session org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

I know there are other similar questions on Stack Overflow but they seem to arise from different conditions, and were not useful in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but if executing the removal *after* the update the problem is gone:

```
public void removeItem() {
    Iterator<ClassA> it = allA.iterator();
    ClassA toRemove = null; 
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ClassA cA = it.next();
        if(cA.hasCondition()){
            toRemove = cA;
            it.remove();
        }
        else {
            cA.update();
        }
    }
    dao.update(allA);
    if(toRemove!=null)dao.remove(toRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [optimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-application-level-repeatable-reads/) mechanism prevents lost updates due to concurrent requests. If you say the database is properly updated, it means some other threads might have attempted to update some entities you've just deleted.

There's always a risk of running into such situations. Most of the time it's better to abandon the request and restart the flow from the latest database entity state.

Comment: Thanks, I found this answer useful (and thus upvoted it) but in the end I managed to solve it by inverting the order of update and removal (see my answer)